# Is quantum immortality true?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

[Quantum Immortality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_suicide_and_immortality) seems like the scariest idea in the history of science. What are the best arguments against this idea?

Comment: The best argument against it is that it is not physics.

Comment: This question would be improved by a link to what the OP considers to be a good presentation of the topic. When I googled on the phrase, the first link I clicked through on seemed to me like clear pseudoscience, since it talked about "quantum" this and that, but in actuality the only element of quantum mechanics used in the argument was either nondeterminism or superposition (can't tell which, because it didn't rise to that level of rigor). There are non-quantum theories that include nondeterminism or superposition.

Comment: "_Quantum immortality_" seems more like a philosophical thing.  Kinda like, we can imagine an infinity of different notions of "_Heaven_" which have different criteria for entry into an afterlife.  Presumably, no matter what you do, some infinitely large subset of those heavens will accept you, while some infinitely large subset may not.  Since these heavens are unfalsifiable hypotheticals, nothing in science objects to the concept of their existence; but, what's there to gain from considering such hypotheticals?  Quantum immortality seems to be much the same, just with some Physics-flavor.

Comment: This question is on hold right now. But according to quantum immortality, somewhere it will be kept open forever, accumulating more and more answers without limit.

Comment: From the Wikipedia entry the question itself provides: "Tegmark explains, however, that life and death situations do not normally hinge upon a sequence of binary quantum events like those in the thought experiment [[reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0101077)]."

Answer (score 1):

Quantum immortality assumes (among other things) that there's always SOME nonzero matrix element between your current state and a state where you keep living. But even if you accept that your consciousness must always locally follow the path that keeps you alive, that DOESN'T imply that there always IS a path that keeps you alive. If the earth exploded tomorrow and all the oxygen was blasted into the interstellar void, you would die. There's no way around it. And maybe, if you are 300 years old, you die, no way around it.

That said, no way to know for sure! If you really want to test quantum immortality, you have to either wait until you're 300 and everyone else you know is long dead, or repeatedly participate in risky activities and see if you miraculously live each time. I recommend the waiting option.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the subjective persistence of consciousness or self is a classical or semi-classical state machine that can be copied or simulated faithfully without falling into the conditions of [No-Cloning theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-cloning_theorem), as long as there are mathematically consistent universe time-slices with a past identical to our present, those mathematical humans must have a consistent subjective experience as any past real or mathematical humans, if the universe they exist on is "physical" or not, is not something they could figure out by experiments, so it will remain a "philosophical" topic both for them and for us.

Having said that, is not something physics can refute, so the whole topic is just philosophy, surely inspired in physics study.

Answer (score 1):

Quantum immortality is false because it fails to take into account the fact that if all versions of you in the multiverse need to be considered, then those versions  with a larger amplitude should be more probable, precisely according to the Born rule.

If one assumes that the probability amplitude does not matter, then it won't matter in general, not just in processes that could lead to your death (from the point of view of other observers). It won't matter for processes that could lead to you appearing out of thin air, either. So, in many places in the universe you could fluctuate into existence with your exact memories you have here now. All these possibilities lead to sort-of Boltzmann brain versions of you, and they should all be equally likely versions of you, despite astronomically small amplitudes.

If we then correct for the flaw of not taking into account probability amplitudes, we can still stick to the assumption of always finding ourselves alive in some state in the multiverse, but now we should consider ourselves to be sampled from all states with a probability given by the Born rule. As you become older and older, versions of you that are not as old will come into play.

A problem here is to have a definition of what constitutes "you". This should be defined using informations stored in your brain, but the whole point of time evolution and the change this implies means that we're not keeping that information the same. So, you'll end up having to consider the set of all possible observers and you are just one such observer sampled from the set of all possible observers.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.06347